# Access-Control-Allow-Origin works only on chrome

Tags: javascript, php, request, cors, axios

I'm using axios to make my request from VueJS frontend. CORS requests do two calls, the first is `OPTIONS` the second with the requested so `POST`in my case.

It works perfectly on Chrome, but if I use Safari or Firefox I only have the `OPTIONS` request. They don't do the `POST` request.

PHP (I'm using Phalcon PHP) :

```
public function JSONBuilderCORS($data, $code) {
    $response = new Response();

    $message = $this->getResponseDescription($code);

    if ($this->request->getServer('HTTP_ORIGIN')) {
        $response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        $response->setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', 86400);
    }

    if ($this->request->isOptions()) {
        if ($this->request->getServer('HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD')) {
            $response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        }

        if ($this->request->getServer('HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS')) {
            $response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
        }

        $response->setStatusCode($code, $message);
        $response->setContent($data);
        return $response;
    }

    $response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->setStatusCode($code, $message);
    $response->setJsonContent($data);

    return $response;
}
```

VueJS :

```
  let config = {
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  };

  axios.post('http://example.com/charge', {
    firstname: this.firstname,
    lastname: this.lastname,
    amount: this.finalAmount * 100,
    source: result.token.id
  },config)
    .then((response) => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.paid = true;
      this.snackbarSuccess = true;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.snackbarError = true;
    });
```

Firefox Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    
1
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    
*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    
GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin 
*
Access-Control-Max-Age  
86400
Connection  
keep-alive
Content-Length  
2
Content-Type    
text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    
Wed, 30 Jan 2019 16:40:13 GMT
Server  
nginx
Status  
200 OK

Request headers (515 B) 
Accept  
text/html,application/xhtml+xm…ml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-Headers  
access-control-allow-origin
Access-Control-Request-Method   
POST
Connection  
keep-alive
Host    
example.com
Origin  
http://localhost:8080
Referer 
http://localhost:8080/payment
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work on the other browser can you help me ?

Comment: Look in the network panel in Safari and tell us what result of the Options request then?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I updated my answer

Comment: Maybe remove some optional stuff to simplify the code. For example, technically you dont need "allow headers" for "content-type" if the value is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". Also not sure you need 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' in the JS code.

Comment: @Stefan I removed but there are no changes

Comment: Remove ALL the headers from your JavaScript, you don't need any of them. You aren't sending urlencoded form data, you are sending an object that will be converted into JSON. This is the default for axios.

Comment: Ok so I just removed `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',` from the JavaScript code and it works... It doesn't works if I remove content-type. I don't know why. CORS is horrible, there are so many ways to make it works and there are so much random answer on the web. I think we need a real answer to understand it :/